# Prevent bat from moving out of bounds in breakout game?

Tags: java

I'm working on a breakout game for an assignment and for part 2 of it I need to include code that stops the bat from being moved out of the boundaries. I'm pretty sure that I need to use an if statements but I don't know what exactly I should put inside the brackets for else (something that will enable the bat to move). I

This is the code in particular I'm talking about.

```
if (dist < 0) 
    {
    }
    else
    {} // move

    if ((dist + 150)> 600)
    {
    }
    else
    {} // move
```

(Part 2 is in the ModelBreakout class).

There are lots of classes and just so many different parts of the code that are to do with the movement of the bat and I don't know what to use for this part, I would appreciate a hint of what I need to do!

Edit: I removed all of the classes because people were complaining. If you would like to view the classes go to [this](http://snowwhite.it.brighton.ac.uk/~mas/mas/courses/ci101.2014/miniprojects/index.html) page and scroll down to the title Mini project: The BreakOut game.

Thanks for any help. I'm not looking for anyone to do my work for me, I would just like some guidance, I've worked out that I need to do an if statement, I'm just not sure of what I need to put inside it.

Comment: Nobody's going to go through your entire program and debug it for you. Extract a simplified short illustration of the problem you're trying to resolve, and ask specific questions about that. Help us help you.

Comment: Most of this isn't my work, it's a program that has been mostly complete that I've been asked to add to. I'm just providing the larger part of the program so that you can gain understanding of the program and actually be able to offer help.

Comment: To add to @keshlam's point - your question has ~500 lines of code in it. Have a look at "[*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" for some tips.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry that there's a lot of code. I don't expect you to look through most of it. I was going to just provide links but it will only let me provide two. If you read my problem and try to understand then the chances are you won't have to look through all of the code.

Comment: General Instructions: find the code which implements bat motion. Add tests which limit its travel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR.

I recently created a similar game. Here's how I implemented it.

**Racket Class**

```
protected static final float MIN_X = 10;
protected static final float MAX_X = 590;

public void moveLeft()
{
    if (x > MIN_X)
    {
        x -= 5;
    }
}

public void moveRight()
{
    if (x < MAX_X)
    {
        x += 5;
    }
}
```

**Player extends Racket**

```
public void process(int key)
{
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_KP_LEFT || key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        moveLeft();
    }
    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_KP_RIGHT || key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        moveRight();
    }
}
```

Edit: This is not the complete classes. It's just some items lifted from them. There's a key listener added to the game which passes the key to Player.process().

Edit 2: Updated my code. Your width is set to 600 so the boundaries can be 10 and 590. This should work for you

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've been looking at what you've done and yeah it looks like it might work, I'll try it out :)

Comment: If you have any questions, feel free to comment here! If the answer works, please remember to mark it as answer ;)

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring what to replace x and distance with in regards to my code... can you explain these variables to me?

Comment: Bat.x is x and distance is how much you want to move the bat. You can hardcode it to say 5 if you want. You can remove the parameter (int distance) and just say x += 5;

Comment: I'm fine with hardcoding the distance, thanks for that feedback :) I'm still having problems though... I need to include left and right within one function moveBat, and I'm not sure what x would be for me. In the gameObject class there's public float getX()  which returns the coordinate of the object... so I'm not sure if I could use that. If you have time could you have a look at the classes that I provided? I don't expect to be spoonfed the answer and I'm trying my best to work out how to do it but I'm not really sure what to do. I've never done anything like this before.

Comment: You will be comparing the Bat.getX() < MIN_X or Bat.getX() > MAX_X and then calling moveBat(-5); or moveBat(5); depending which way you want to move it

Comment: X -= 5 is the same as your program calling moveBat(-5)

Comment: I don't think I explained myself right, moveBat is what I'm creating the code inside.

Comment: MoveBat(int x) { if (x > 0){ Bat.setX(Bat.getX() +x); } else { Bat.setX(Bat.getX() -x);}

Comment: Sorry, I've left the computer. That's a quick method written from my phone.

Comment: It's okay I appreciate that you're trying to help! I get an error saying cannot find variable - symbol Bat? :/

Comment: I dont understand how your code works but what you need to do is get the X coord of the bar, however it's possibly (usually calling getX() on the object) and compare this to the constants you've created (10 and 590). Provided the bat is still inside the boundaries, you should be able yo move the bat using the moveBat() method. What this method needs to do is set the X coord of the Bat to what it is, plus or minus a value (we'll use 5) depending on whether you want to move it left or right

Comment: The thing is my bat moves fine already, I literally just want to create the if else statement using 10 and 590 and from that be able to have it so that if the movement would go below 10 or above 590 it prevents the bat from moving. I don't know if this helps at all but the code already existing in moveBat is Debug.trace( "Model: Move bat = %6.2f", dist );
        bat.moveX(dist);. I'm sorry for being do difficult to help, I'll try my best to work out how to do it myself.. :)

Comment: Join me in the chatroom please

Comment: I don't have enough reputation unfortunately! :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78033/discussion-between-alan-and-edwards).

Comment: Hey!, sorry to be a bother but when you have time could you please get back to me :)

Comment: Sure, head over to the chat again

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the classes there are built in methods for each object on the screen, so you could do something like this:

```
If( Bat.GetX() < 0 ) {
  Bat.moveX( *INSERT THE X HERE* )
}
```

And you also could do a the same thing for the max width. Also if you do a simple fix like this make sure to change the refresh rate of the screen, otherwise you will see the bat Jumping to the new position.